# Flex 3: Strange behavior when function does a simple math operation

Tags: apache-flex

So, in one of my modules, a variable named numDays is created by looping through some XML data and finding the maximum value of an xml field calls days.  After the numDays variable is found, I use it to find the width of a canvas by doing:

```
wrapper.width = numDays * parentApplication.oneDay;
```

(oneDay is a value determined by dividing the width of the window by 14)

So, now that I know how wide the wrapper canvas is, I can start to fill it.  I have four items that are going into the wrapper: 1) Role description, 2) left controller, 3) name textbox (auto suggest component), 4) right controller.  The width of the role description is 30px.  The left and right controllers are 20 px each.  So in order to get the width of the name textbox, I have a function that does the following:

```
nameTextbox.width = wrapper.width - 70;
```

for some reason when I do this, the application doesn't load fully.  It pretty much stalls out.  I have 30 "projects" with 15 "positions" within each of them.  the wrapper.width is describing the width of a position, so there are 450 name textboxes trying to be figured out.  Is this why it's messing up?

*EDIT*

So, from the main application, the project module is called.  From within the project module, a list is created with a datasource of "positionsAC":

```
<mx:List id="wholePosition" dataProvider="{positionsAC}" width="100%" height="100%" paddingBottom="0" paddingLeft="0" paddingRight="0" paddingTop="0" backgroundAlpha="0" verticalScrollPolicy="off" itemRenderer="modules.position" useRollOver="false" selectable="false">
```

Below is a c/p of the position module in it's entirety

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Module xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" xmlns:components="com.hillelcoren.components.*" dataChange="allData = data as Array" layout="absolute" creationComplete="init();" horizontalScrollPolicy="off">
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.controls.Alert;

        [Bindable] public var positionInfo:Array;
        [Bindable] public var wholePositionID:Number;
        [Bindable] public var allData:Array;

        [Bindable] public var positions:XML;            
        [Bindable] public var startOffset:Number;
        [Bindable] public var numDays:Number;
        [Bindable] public var role:String;
        [Bindable] public var studentID:Number;
        [Bindable] public var conflict:Number;
        [Bindable] public var studentType:String;
        [Bindable] public var showInPrinciple:Number;

        [Bindable] public var positionX:Number = 0;
        [Bindable] public var positionWidth:Number = 0;
        [Bindable] public var sName:String = new String;
        [Bindable] public var asAC:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection;
        [Bindable] public var conflictBG:uint = 0xffffff;
        [Bindable] public var roleColor:uint = 0x000000;

        private function init():void
        {
            if (allData)
            {
                getInfo(allData);
                setBGColor();
                getPositionX();
                getPositionWidth();
                getRightStudents();
            }
        }

        private function getInfo(a:Array):void
        {
            var tempArray:Array = new Array;

            startOffset = Number(a[0]);
            numDays = Number(a[1]);
            positionWidth = parentApplication.oneDay * numDays;
            setStudentNameW();
            role = a[2];
            studentID = Number(a[3]);
            tempArray = parentApplication.studentsDBIDDict[String(studentID)] as Array;
            conflict = Number(a[4]);
            studentType = a[5];
            sName = "test";
            showInPrinciple = a[6];
        }

        private function setStudentNameW():void
        {
            if (numDays == 1)
            {
                studentName.width = 55;
                studentName.x = 37;
                contractLeft.visible = false;
                contractRight.visible = false;
            }
            else if (numDays == 2)
            {
                Alert.show("HI");
                studentName.width = 133;
            }
            else if (numDays == 3)
                studentName.width = 230;
            else if (numDays == 4)
                studentName.width = 330;

            if (numDays > 1)
            {
                studentName.x = 47;
                contractLeft.visible = true;
                contractRight.visible = true;                    
            }
        }

        public function setBGColor():void
        {
            if (conflict == 1)
                conflictBG = parentApplication.errorColor;
            else if (conflict == 2)
                conflictBG = parentApplication.okErrorColor;
            else
                conflictBG = 0xFFFFFF;
        }

        private function getPositionX():void
        {
            positionX = parentApplication.oneDay * startOffset - 1;
        }

        private function getPositionWidth():void
        {
            positionWidth = parentApplication.oneDay * numDays;
        }

        private function getRightStudents():void
        {
            if (studentType == "freshman")
                makeASAC(parentApplication.freshmanAC);
            else if (studentType == "bfa1")
                makeASAC(parentApplication.bfa1AC);
            else if (studentType == "bfa2")
                makeASAC(parentApplication.bfa2AC);
            else if (studentType == "bfa3")
                makeASAC(parentApplication.bfa3AC);
            else if (studentType == "mfa1")
                makeASAC(parentApplication.mfa1AC);
            else if (studentType == "mfa2")
                makeASAC(parentApplication.mfa2AC);
            else if (studentType == "mfa3")
                makeASAC(parentApplication.mfa3AC);
            else if (studentType == "mfaw1")
                makeASAC(parentApplication.mfaw1AC);
            else if (studentType == "mfaw2")
                makeASAC(parentApplication.mfaw2AC);
            else if (studentType == "mfaw3")
                makeASAC(parentApplication.mfaw3AC);
        }

        private function makeASAC(students:ArrayCollection):void
        {
            for (var i:int = 0; i < students.length; i++)
                asAC.addItem(parentApplication.getStudentName(students.getItemAt(i)));
        }

        private function posLength(whichSide:String, expandContract:String):void
        {
            if (whichSide == 'l')
            {
                if (expandContract == 'e')
                {
                    if (startOffset > 0)
                    {
                        numDays++;
                        startOffset--;
                        getPositionX();
                        getPositionWidth();
                    }
                }
                else if (expandContract == 'c')
                {
                    if (numDays > 1)
                    {
                        numDays--;
                        startOffset++;
                        getPositionX();
                        getPositionWidth();
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (whichSide == 'r')
            {
                if (expandContract == 'e')
                {
                    if (numDays + startOffset < parentDocument.projectLength)
                    {
                        numDays++;
                        getPositionX();
                        getPositionWidth();
                    }
                }
                else if (expandContract == 'c')
                {
                    if (numDays > 1)
                    {
                        numDays--;
                        getPositionX();
                        getPositionWidth();
                    }
                }
            }

            //parentApplication.conflicts();
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>    

<mx:Canvas id="positionWrapper" width="{positionWidth}" height="25" backgroundColor="#ffffff" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" borderColor="#000000" borderStyle="solid" borderThickness="1">
    <mx:Text id="roleText" text="{role}" width="25" y="3" color="{roleColor}" fontSize="11" fontWeight="bold" click="parentApplication.getDictLen(parentApplication.studentsDBIDDict)" />
    <mx:Canvas id="leftSide" x="25" width="22" height="100%" mouseOver="expandLeft.visible = true; contractLeft.visible = true;" mouseOut="expandLeft.visible = false; contractLeft.visible = false;" backgroundColor="{conflictBG}" horizontalScrollPolicy="off"> 
        <mx:Image id="expandLeft" source="images/addRed.png" y="5" click="posLength('l', 'e')" mouseOver="parentApplication.switchCursor(true);" mouseOut="parentApplication.switchCursor(false);" visible="false" />
        <mx:Image id="contractLeft" source="images/minusRed.png" x="10" y="5" click="posLength('l', 'c')" mouseOver="parentApplication.switchCursor(true);" mouseOut="parentApplication.switchCursor(false);" visible="false" />
    </mx:Canvas>
    <components:AutoComplete id="studentName" textAlign="center"
        dataProvider="{asAC}"
        x="47" y="3"
    />
    <mx:Image id="showSNW" source="images/searchicon.png" x="{(studentName.width + studentName.x) - 12}" y="5" visible="false" mouseOver="parentApplication.switchCursor(true); studentName.enabled = false;" mouseOut="parentApplication.switchCursor(false); studentName.enabled = true; showSNW.visible = false;" />
    <mx:Canvas id="rightSide" x="{positionWrapper.width - 22}" width="20" height="100%" mouseOver="expandRight.visible = true; contractRight.visible = true;" mouseOut="expandRight.visible = false; contractRight.visible = false;" backgroundColor="{conflictBG}" horizontalScrollPolicy="off">
        <mx:Image id="contractRight" source="images/minusRed.png" y="5" click="posLength('r', 'c')" visible="false" mouseOver="parentApplication.switchCursor(true);" mouseOut="parentApplication.switchCursor(false);" />
        <mx:Image id="expandRight" source="images/addRed.png" x="10" y="5" click="posLength('r', 'e')" visible="false" mouseOver="parentApplication.switchCursor(true);" mouseOut="parentApplication.switchCursor(false);" />
    </mx:Canvas>
</mx:Canvas>
```

Comment: Are you sure that wrapper and/or nameTextbox have been created when you start assigning values to their width? It might be that they haven't been created and you're hitting a null pointer. Have you tried running with the debugger?

Comment: Sounds like their is a lot going on; but I don't understand what the problem is.  What does "Stall out" mean.  Are you having compile issues or runtime issues.  When you say you have 30 projects; do you mean 30 different Flash Builder projects?  When you talk about "one of your modules" do you mean a Flex Module or are you using the term generically to mean "encapsulated class"?

Comment: do you have a debugger?

Have you ensured that nameTextBox is not null?

Comment: @Flextras, he probably means hangs, as usually happens when an uncaught exception occurs on a non-debugger Flash Player

Comment: @Pranav Hosangadi IF he has 30 different Flash Builder Projects; each creating a different Module; then it's not unheard of for all open projects to recompile just because a single file was saved and that caused the workspace to refresh.  The, it could be the IDE that is hanging, not the flash player. Both are an equally plausible scenario based on the information in the question.

Comment: @Flextras Well, FB isn't likely to hang when he adds `nameTextbox.width = wrapper.width - 70;` to the code, is it?

Comment: I've added how the position is called, and also the code that composes the position module... hopefully this will help clear things up

Comment: hmmm.... if i tell setStudentNameW() to only run only for the first 10 projects, it works just fine.  It's when I tell it to run for all 30 projects that it hangs.

Answer (score 0):

Best to get a debugger. Flash Builder 4 is a pretty decent one, and they even give out free standard licenses to

- Students, faculty and staff of eligible educational institutions
- Software developers who are affected by the current economic condition and are currently unemployed
- Event attendees who receive a special promotional code at their event

[Check this out](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/flex/free/)

Also, get debugger versions of the latest Flash Player [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer.html)

The free standard might take some time to come, but you can always use the free trial in the meanwhile.

When you debug, check that nameTextBox is not null.

Comment: Thanks for the info... I actually work for FSU (No 'Noles) so I signed up for the free copy of flash builder :D